# Iterating over a df based a unique values of a column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to iterate over a data to get the data in terms of the unique values of a column. First, I made a list of unique values of the target column, and then tried to define a function that will result the data for a specific unique value. However, it seems I am not quite successful. Can you please help me to deal with the issue?

[image: Sample Data]

```
uniq_list = df2['Sum of Qtd'].unique().tolist()

def unique_data(uniq):
    unique_list=[]
    for uniq in uniq_list:
        if df2[df2['Sum of Qtd'] == uniq]:
            res_df2 = []
            res_df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df2.columns)
            res_df2.append(uniq)
        unique_list.append(res_df2) 


for uniq in uniq_list:
    print(unique_data(uniq)
```

But the error I am getting is as below,

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-31-0455c2449f78> in <module>()
>       1 for uniq in uniq_list:
> ----> 2     print(unique_data(uniq))
> 
> <ipython-input-29-75d579a4768f> in unique_data(uniq)
>       2     unique_list=[]
>       3     for uniq in uniq_list:
> ----> 4         if df2[df2['Sum of Qtd'] == uniq]:
>       5             res_df2 = []
>       6             res_df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df2.columns)
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
> __nonzero__(self)    1571         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "    1572                          "Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
> -> 1573                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))    1574     1575     __bool__ = __nonzero__
> 
> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

After some improvements and solving the error issue the modified code is like as below, but still I am unable to create the subset of data based on the unique values of column 'Sum of Qtd'. Could you please give me some hints how can I do so?

```
def unique_data(uniq):
    unique_list=[]
    for i in uniq_list:
        res_df2 = []
        res_df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df2.columns)
        if df2.loc[df2['Sum of Qtd'] != uniq].empty:
            res_df2.append(df2)
            Q1 = df2.Sales.quantile(0.25)
            Q3 = df2.Sales.quantile(0.75)
            IQR = Q3 - Q1
            mask = (df2.Sales < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df2.Sales > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))
            df2[mask] = np.nan    
        unique_list.append(res_df2)
        print(unique_list)
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You pass `uniq` as a parameter to the function, but then ignore it and overwrite it when you loop using `for uniq in uniq_list:`. And `uniq_list` is empty so the loop should never run.

Comment: @jezrael Done. Please have a look.

Comment: @Denziloe len(uniq_list) is 3617. It's not empty. I know there is something wrong in code but couldnt understand what. Should I replace uniq with any other identity?

Comment: It is empty within the function because you do this `unique_list=[]`.

Comment: @Denziloe I have modified the code a bit, can you have a look at the post once again?

Comment: Do you intentionally have two different variables named `unique_list` and `uniq_list`?

Comment: @Denziloe Yes. uniq_list is the separate list of all unique values of column 'Sum of Qtd'. and actually I created unique_list with the hope that it will have all the subset of data for each unique value of uniq_list. But I couldn't figure out how can I create the subsets of data for each unique values.

Comment: You should use variable names that actually describe the variable. Arbitrarily removing an 'e' from the spelling of one of the variables creates code that is completely unreadable.